# Acumatica BQL verification failed

Tags: acumatica

I have built a Process page in Acumatica working off of a fairly complicated BQL statement with a ProcessFilter of 3 elements.  The process works fine, but if you refresh the grid or hit any of the grid controls when one or more of the records in the grid is selected (via selected checkbox I've added to the DAC), you get a "BQL verification failed!" Error citing a PX.DATA.Select2.. string.  Why would the line being selected interfere with refreshing from the view?

Comment: present your bql statement. Maybe something wrong with it

Comment: public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<PositivePay.APAdjust, ProcessFilter, LeftJoin<APPayment, On<APPayment.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr>,
 And<APPayment.docType,Equal<APAdjust.adjgDocType>>>,
    LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<APAdjust.vendorID>>,
    LeftJoin<CashAccount,On<APPayment.cashAccountID,Equal<CashAccount.accountID>>>>> ,

Comment: Where2<
   Where<APPayment.paymentMethodID,Like<CHK>, And<APPayment.docType, Like<CHKtype>>>,
   And<
    Where<APAdjust.released,NotEqual<Zero>,
    And<
      Where<APPayment.cashAccountID, Equal<Current<ProcessFilter.payAccountID>>,
      And<
      Where<APPayment.stubCntr,Greater<Zero>,
         And<
        Where<APAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<Current<ProcessFilter.tranType>>, 
        And<
          Where<Current<ProcessFilter.unprinted>,Equal<False>,Or<APAdjust.usrPPprinted, LessEqual<Zero>>>

Comment: Please add declaration of PositivePay.APAdjust, because I can't even compile your BQL

Comment: The only thing I add is the following:

Comment: #region Selected
        public abstract class selected : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected bool? _Selected = false;
        [PXBool]
        [PXDefault(false)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
        public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
        #endregion

Comment: #region UsrPPprinted
        public abstract class usrPPprinted : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected int? _UsrPPprinted;
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Export Count", IsReadOnly = true)]
        [PXDefault(0)]
        public virtual int? UsrPPprinted
        {
            get
            {
                return this._UsrPPprinted;
            }
            set
            {
                this._UsrPPprinted = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that early on I had created a Constant (Zero) that was an Int32 while the field I was trying to compare it to in my BQL for the View was an int.  That will trigger the validation error, even though the BQL executes on loading.